# Xcode preferences across multiple computers?

Tags: xcode, preferences

I run Xcode on both my laptop and desktop. I'm constantly tweaking my setup with regards to key bindings.

Rather than try to get both configurations identical by hand, is there any way to create the configuration on one computer and then share it via dropbox (for example) for the other to use? Perhaps by symlinking the laptop's configuration file to one stored on dropbox?

Very curious how others handle this situation.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 23):

It looks like the Xcode preference file is now named

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

Answer (score 15):

As others have mentioned, the location for things like key bindings, color themes, snippets, etc. is here...

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData`

This is what I move from machine to machine.

The rest of the files in `Library/preferences` from the other-mentioned answers are more non-user-specific things. I find I usually don't have to worry about them (translation: I don't miss them if I don't copy them, but key bindings and themes I'm lost without.)

Answer (score 14):

Most of your Xcode settings are in the Preferences file at:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist
```

This doesn't include templates.

Comment: And then an automator or apple script utility to copy the dropbox version to the library?

Comment: Do you know whether there is anything in the plist that is computer specific, that would make it improper to share across multiple computers?

I'll try syncing the two when I get home tonight. Thanks for the advice on the file.

Comment: @JoePasq I was thinking of just moving the com.apple.Xcode.plist to ~/Dropbox, then ln -s ~/Dropbox/com.apple.Xcode.plist ~/Library/Preferences/

Don't know whether that would be less safe than just running an automator script to copy back and forth.

Comment: Doesn't look like symlinking it will work. It seems that Xcode just replaces the symlink with a static file when it writes to it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There's also some stuff in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` (particularly `/UserData`).

Answer (score 8):

To move your **Fonts & Colors** theme you need to copy

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/yourTheme.dvtcolortheme`

file from one system to another.

For Xcode preferences as mentioned by one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791035/468724), you need to copy

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`